# Iterate over pandas DataFrame to calculate new row value

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to iterate over Pandas dataframe and calculate the a new row value. Except for Year 1, 2010, rent increases at an rate of 2%. I'd like to calculate this new rent and update the rent column.

The 2% is calculate off of the previous year's value, so it's like rolling 2%.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   "Year": ['2010','2011','2012','2013','2014'],
                   "Rent": ['1000','1000','1000','1000','1000']
                 })


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[index, "Rent"] = round(row['Year']*row['Rent'],0) + round(2*row['Rent']/100,0)
```

My attempt doesn't quite work.

The expected output / modified DataFrame would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   "Year": ['2010','2011','2012','2013','2014'],
                   "Rent": ['1000','1020','1040.4','1060.8','1082]
                 })
```

- there might be some rounding error, so approx values is fine.

Comment: please share the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a way to solve your problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   "Year": ['2010','2011','2012','2013','2014'],
                   "Rent": ['1000','1000','1000','1000','1000']
                 })

counter = 1
for i in df.loc[1:, 'Rent']:
    i = (2 * int(df.loc[counter-1, 'Rent']) /100) + int(df.loc[counter-1, 'Rent'])
    print('rent: ' + str(df.loc[counter-1, 'Rent']))
    df.loc[counter, 'Rent'] = i
    counter += 1
```

output:

```
    Year    Rent
0   2010    1000
1   2011    1020.0
2   2012    1040.4
3   2013    1060.8
4   2014    1081.2
```

Comment: Can you print the output dataframe as well.